# useEffect to check for update of useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem that `useState` whenever is updated calls the previous value.
Is there any way to use `useEffect` to check it for update?

```js
  const [thisButtomSelected, setThisButtomSelected] = useState({
    thisVal: 0,
    thisIndex: 0,
  })
   const onClick = e => {  
    setThisButtomSelected({ thisVal: e.currentTarget.value, thisIndex: e.currentTarget.id });
  }

  <li id="list" key={item.id}>
    <button
      value={item.value}
      id={index}
      className={isEqual(thisButtomSelected, { thisVal: item.value, thisIndex: index }) 
        ? 'button-selected' : 'button'
      }
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      {item.displayValue}
    </button>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not really clear about what you want to do, but having `useEffect` be aware of state change could be done like so :

```js
useEffect(()=>{
 // do things

},[thisButtomSelected])
```

The function inside `useEffect` will get executed whenever `thisButtomSelected` changes and also when the component render the first time.